# How to align label and text box in line through html?

Tags: html, css

With the below code, the summary and it's text box are aligned inline.But the text box for description is appearing below the label 'description'. How can I make it align inline? Please help me in resolving this.

```css
    .left {
      width: 30%;
      float: left;
      text-align: right;
    }
    .right {
      width: 65%;
      margin-left: 10px;
      float: left;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-3 col-xs-4 col-xs-push-2">
        <h1 class="text-center" style="font-family:Colonna MT;font-size:50px;color:ForestGreen ;">Post Your Ad</h1>
        <form action="post" class="login-form">
          <div>
            <label class="left">Summary:</label>
            <input class="right" type="text" name="Summary" size="50">
          </div>
          <div>
            <label class="left">Description:</label>
            <input class="right" type="text" name="Description" style="height:100px;width:400px">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean align it to the middle, vertically?

Comment: No, I want the label and it's textbox to display horizontally(i.e, textbox should be displayed beside the label).

Comment: Style the div with label and input to float left

Comment: @Rahul that `<input>` should probably be a `<textarea>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfXUr/605/)**

If you need multi line `text` box, use `textarea` instead of input type `text`

```
    <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-control-label text-right">Summary</label>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Summary" size="50">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-control-label text-right">Description</label>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="Description"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Edit:**

As you mentioned, its not `form-control` class, its `form-control-label`.. You can get more info **[here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#using-the-grid)**

**Updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfXUr/606/):** To change the height, try chnaging the value of `rows="8"` for `<textarea>`

Comment: This looks good.Thanks!! But the box size is very small..How can I increase them?

Comment: @Rahul: which box size you want to increase? you can adjust col-md-6 to any value from 1to 12 cols according to your requirement

Comment: thanks alot :) it worked for me. Btw, Can you please let me know the use of 'form-control' in the label tag? am not sure of it.

Comment: by adjusting col-md , i was able to increase the width of the box.But how can I adjust height of the description box?

Comment: Thankyou :)it worked. But when I added one more textbox(price)(, it is not aligned with the other boxes. pls check here http://jsfiddle.net/Rahul_16/jfXUr/607/   and provide a solution

Comment: you the same class used in other two labels, here you used different.. try like this `col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-control-label text-right`.. it ll work fine [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/jfXUr/609/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105249/discussion-between-rahul-and-g-l-p).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bootstrap (as the classes on your code suggest). I would recommend using their form layout options. Sounds like you want a Horizontal Form:

[Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

For Example:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="summary" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Summary</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="summary" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" style="height:100px;width:400px" />
    </div>
  </div>      
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input class="right" type="text" name="Description" style="height:100px;width:400px;">
```

Remove width from input of description, also please change to textarea, instead of input.

Comment: after using textarea, all the code is displayed in the description textbox by default.

Answer (score 1):

You have already used bootstrap framework.so that there is no need to write extra css for inline forms. follow the following code

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-lg-3 control-label ">City</label>
      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group ">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <label class="sr-only" for="city">City</label> 
              <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="form-control " placeholder="E.g. Thrissur" >
            </div>
          </div> 
          <div class="form-group ">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <label class="sr-only" for="county">County</label> 
              <input type="text" id="county" name="county" class="form-control " placeholder="E.g. India" >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/d6tscd18/

```
.left {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
.right {
  width: 65%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Though it is displaying properly in fiddle, it is not proper in browser.Still the description box is coming below the label

Comment: Doesn't it make a difference which browser you use?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>sample</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .left {
          width: 30%;
          display: inline-block;
          text-align: right
      }
      .right {
          margin-left: 10px;
          display: inline-block;
      }
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-3 col-xs-4 col-xs-push-2">
            <h1 class="text-center" style="font-family:Colonna MT;font-                    size:50px;color:ForestGreen ; text-align: center">Post Your Ad</h1>
 <form action="post" class="login-form">
      <div>
        <label class="left">Summary:</label>
        <input class="right" type="text" name="Summary" size="50" style="width:400px">
      </div>
    <div>
       <label class="left">Description:</label>       
       <input class="right" type="text" name="Description" style="height:100px;width:400px">
   </div>
 </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is coming inline vertically that too not proper.Pls review once.

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble getting it in place you can also force a table layout without using tables:

```
.login-form {
    display: table;
}
.login-form>div {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
...
```

Adding a div around the inputs and a "cell" class (and shouldn't it be a textarea?):

```
...
<form action="post" class="login-form">
    <div>
        <label class="left cell">Summary:</label>
        <div class="cell">
            <input class="right" type="text" name="Summary" size="50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="left cell">Description:</label>
        <div class="cell">
            <textarea class="right" name="Description" style="height:100px;width:400px"></textarea>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
...
```

[Check it here](https://jsfiddle.net/acwacccx/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the style attribute from the description input type, it will then appear as the summary input box.

```
<form action="post" class="login-form">
  <div>
    <label class="left">Summary:</label>
    <input class="right" type="text" name="Summary" size="50" style="width:400px">
  </div>
<div>
   <label class="left">Description:</label>       
   <input class="right" type="text" name="Description">
```